# vb.net and mysql to retrive all columns of 3 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

how can i retrieve data of all columns from 3 tables where quotation no is common in all 3 tables where 1 table has quotation no primary key and other 2 tables has quotation no as foreign key

Answer (score 0):

if i get what you want, you can use join

```
    select * from table2,table3 
    join table1 on table1.id = idfkey 
    where table3.idfkey = table2.idfkey
```